# Matrix "a" is not getting reset to null matrix

Tags: python, matrix, backtracking

For this python code:

```py
def isSafe(maze, visited, x, y):
    return 0 <= x < len(maze) and 0 <= y < len(maze[0]) and \
           not (maze[x][y] == 0 or visited[x][y])

def find_4path(maze,i,j,dest,visited,a,f,count):
    
    c=0
        #new
    if (i,j)==dest:
        f.append(a)
        f[-1]=[n for n in a]
        for n in range(len(a)):
            a.pop()
        #old
    #if (i,j)==dest:
        #f.append(a)
        #a=[]
        #c+=1
        #print(a,"\n",f,"\n",c)
        #if c==count:
            #return 1
    
    visited[i][j]=True
    
    if isSafe(maze,visited,i+1,j):
        a.append((i+1,j))
        print(a)
        find_4path(maze,i+1,j,dest,visited,a,f,count)
        
    if isSafe(maze,visited,i-1,j):
        a.append((i-1,j))
        print(a)
        find_4path(maze,i-1,j,dest,visited,a,f,count)
    
    if isSafe(maze,visited,i,j-1):
        a.append((i,j-1))
        print(a)
        find_4path(maze,i,j-1,dest,visited,a,f,count)
    
    if isSafe(maze,visited,i,j+1):
        a.append((i,j+1))
        print(a)
        find_4path(maze,i,j+1,dest,visited,a,f,count)
    
    visited[i][j]=False
    if len(a)!=0:
        a.pop()

def find(maze, src, dest):

    # get source cell (i, j)
    i, j = src

    # get destination cell (x, y)
    x, y = dest

    # base case: invalid input
    if not maze or not len(maze) or not maze[i][j] or not maze[x][y]:
        return 0

    # `N × N` matrix
    N = len(maze)

    # 2D matrix to keep track of cells involved in the current path
    visited = [[False for x in range(N)] for y in range(N)]
    a=[]
    f=[]
    count=6

    # start from source cell (i, j)
    return find_4path(maze, i, j, dest, visited,a,f,count)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    maze=[[0,0,1,1,1],[1,1,1,0,1],[1,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,0,0]]

    src=(3,0)

    dest=(1,4)

    print(find(maze, src, dest))
```

In `def find_4path => if (i, j) = dest=> f.append(a) a=[]`, after matrix `f` gets its first entry, the code stops working as it should.
After `f.append(a)`, `a` should become a null matrix, but it does not.

output of 1st and 2nd excution:

```py
[(4, 0)]

[(4, 0), (4, 1)]

[(4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1)]

...

...

...

[(4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4)]
[(4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)]

[]

 [[(4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)]]

 1

#here matrix `a` should be null matrix i.e. `a=[]`

[(4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0)]

[(4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (1, 0)]

[(4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0),(1,0),(1,1)]

...

...

...

[]

 [[(4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)]]

 #here value of `c` should be 2

1
```

**Please point out what is wrong in this code**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List changes unexpectedly after assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/16757174). Note that you're doing `f.append(a)` rather than `f.append(a.copy())`

Comment: I have done some changes to the code. And the problem with matrix "a" have been sold. But i am still not able to get the final result as expected.

Comment: Final expected result: f= [[(4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(2, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(2, 0), (2,1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(3,1),(2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(3, 1), (2, 1), (2,0),(1,0),(1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(4,0),(4,1),(3,1),(2,1),(2, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)]]

Comment: Final output: f= [[(3, 0), (4, 0), (4, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(2, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(2, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(3, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)], [(2, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 4)]]